# Displaying Text on SVG

Tags: html, svg

I have a very graphical website that I'm rendering with svg. The issue I'm having is that I need to display some text on the image, and since most browsers don't support automatic line breaking in the  element I'm using a `<foreignObject>` to add a `<div>` inside the svg.

While this works relatively well in Firefox, Chrome handles this very poorly. I'm wondering if I should try to make a `<div>` in the html that would float over the frames but I think it would be difficult to position this element consistently. So, does anyone have any ideas? Here's a link to the page that I'm working on: http://okcomputerstl.com/K9_Athletic_Club/services.html

Comment: So I tried using SVGweb but it didn't display the whole image. I'm wondering if I should give up my dreams of a completely resolution independent site until SVG is better developed and instead just use images to make the site work

Comment: I should say "until browser support of SVG is better"

Answer (score 1):

Check out [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/).

1. It is essentially a cross browser framework for advanced SVG.
2. It has good documentation and support(sencha)
3. It is maturing at version 2.1
4. It is free.

Here is a text [example](http://raphaeljs.com/text-rotation.html). It does typography well in my experience.

Comment: Do you know how I could move my existing SVG file into Raphael?

Comment: Happy to help. Dmitry Baranovskiy(creator of Raphael) is a remarkable individual. http://www.slideshare.net/Dmitry.Baranovskiy/javascript-enter-the-dragon

Comment: That is a good question. Thinking... I can't say I know off-hand best-practice for porting SVG to RaphaelJS. This would be benefical to hear the communities take. +1 to you. I hope to see it, and would contribute something should it come to mind. In the past, I take it line by line. This is good for success, but maybe there is another way... Line-by-line is my current thought. Hope that helps! All the best, Nash

Answer (score 1):

If your content needs automatic flow layout then go with HTML, and just add the svg borders or backgrounds as needed.

If your content is mostly graphics, and you don't need to have automatic flow layout then avoid foreignObject altogether and use one or more <text> elements instead.

SVGWeb doesn't handle foreignObject (or html inside svg) at all AFAIK.